# How to use PowerShell Community Extensions Ping-host?

Tags: command-line, powershell, script, ping

I came across this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470936/fast-ping-function-for-powershell) and would like to try to use the cmdlet `Ping-Host` from [PSCX](https://pscx.codeplex.com/) ([link](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2014/10/24/pscx-3-2-0-available/)).  However, there is `-1` documentation about any of the cmdlets (including [what's in the package](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hV-05TLiiLU)) online whatsoever (quite an impressive feat actually), and even the developer tells someone to [use the man page command (in the comments)](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2014/10/24/pscx-3-2-0-available/).

The problem is that the man page breaks Power Shell somehow.  I'm trying to use the -detailed option and get stuck with this:

[image]

I can't scroll up, I can't type, I can't do anything in the window that i would expect to be able to do.  I can close the window, but since I can't get this text any other way, I'm forced to scroll **line-by-line** until I hit the error (separate issue).

The command I gave was `help ping-host -detailed`.  I believe I also tried `-full` and got similar results.

I looked in the PowerShell modules folder, but don't see anything new.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

Where can I find documentation on this command, and others, included with the PSCX installer?

Adding insult to injury, it seems that the author doesn't' want you usinf Ping-Host.  I get the following error for the command `ping-host $ip.("IPAddress") -count 1 -timeout 1 -quiet`

```
WARNING: [localhost]:The command 'Ping-Host' is obsolete. The PSCX\Ping-Host cmdlet is obsolete and will be removed in the next version of PSCX. Use the built-in Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Test-Connection cmdlet instead.
```

Ping-Host lets you set a timeout in milliseconds, presumably in an attempt to speed things up.  `Test-Connection`'s timeout is seconds, not milliseconds.  It's reeeeeeally slow, even at 1.

**What got me going**

Ping_Host wasn't any faster than Test-Connection or Test-NetConnection, so I kept looking.  I settled on this script: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Fast-asynchronous-ping-IP-d0a5cf0e/

Comment: You can always look at the source.  However, based on what I can tell, that project has been dead for 3+ years

Comment: By the way, does "To exit the “less” paging utility, press the ‘q’ key.", work for you?  What makes you think that output isn't complete by the way?  That appears to outline all the parameters for the cmdlet

Comment: I tried looking at the source, but I couldn't find it.  Q did not exit the failed state.

Comment: It's on CodePlex... You linked to the website which has the source code

Comment: Why do you want to use a 1.0 cmdlet which was replaced by a cmdlet by Microsoft in a newer version of PowerShell

Comment: I want to quickly ping 2000ish IP addresses and find which ones are alive.  This is where I wound up.  And the codeplex site has a spot for source, but it's endless folder structure and nary a .ps1 file I can see.  I was expecting a text or ps1 file to be on my hard drive somewhere.  This is supposed to be scripting, but rocket surgery.

Comment: Download the source, load the VS project, and search for the cmdlet your looking for.  Outside of building it yourself and making it so the cmdlet you want to use is usable I am not sure what your question actually is.  The reason there are no PowerShell script files is because the author built them.  Just like the built-in cmdlets don't have .ps1 files

Comment: Ping_Host wasn't any faster than Test-Connection, so I kept looking.  I settled on this script: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Fast-asynchronous-ping-IP-d0a5cf0e/